# What should I use instead of document.domain to get the domain?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, deprecated, deprecation-warning

It appears that `document.domain` is deprecated:

[image: document domain is deprecated]

[mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain) also say:

> Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible;

However, I don't seem to find anywhere what can I use instead, to **get** the domain. I don't need to **set**, only **get**.

Other articles I read about the deprecation only mention about the alternative for the **set** problem, but they don't mention a solution/alternative for those who just want to **get** the domain.

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/immutable-document-domain/
https://portswigger.net/daily-swig/disavowed-chrome-plans-to-deprecate-document-domain-lays-the-groundwork-for-shift-in-browser-security

Comment: You can use `Origin` header in HTTP

Comment: `document.location`, `document.location.host`

Comment: @JanPfeifer — They aren't using HTTP here.

Comment: you can try `location.hostname`

Comment: @kartarkat - ah, thanks! I actually found that and just posted an answer myself, with that one. That does seems to be the best alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the best alternative I could find: `location.hostname`

Seems to contain only the domain and subdomain, without the port, similar to the result of `document.domain`.